# Need Help on Mongo DB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

There is an existing person collection in the system which is like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("536378bcc9ecd7046700001f"),
    "engagements":{
       "5407357013875b9727000111" : {
            "role" : "ADMINISTRATOR",
        },
       "5407357013875b9727000222" : {
            "role" : "DEVELOPER",
        }
    }
}
```

So that multiple user objects can have the same engagement with a specific role, I need to fire a query in this hierarchy where I can get all the persons which have a specific engagement in the engagements property of person collection.

I want to get all the persons which have 
`5407357013875b9727000222` in the engagements.

I know `$in` operator could be used but the problem is that I need to compare the keys of the sub Json engagements.

Comment: It is impossible to tell what exactly do you want here. Also how jquery is connected to mongodb? Do not randomly add tags to your questions.

Comment: There's nothing specific to json about this question. The tag won't help (but it will litter people's question feeds)

Comment: just did it alright!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's as simple as this:

```
 db.users.find({'engagements.5407357013875b9727000222': {$exists: true}})
```

If you want to match against multiple engagement ids, then you'll have to use `$or`. Sorry, no `$in` for you here.

Note, however, that you need to restructure your data, as this one can't be indexed to help this concrete query. Here I assume you care about performance and this query is used often enough to have impact on the database.